# How to get the $atts of a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have the following shortcode:

```
[video width="400" height="400" mp4="http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/uploads/2014/06/Facebook.mp4"][/video]
```

I need to get every single atts a single variable, I mean, I need something like this

```
$width = 400
$height = 400
$file = http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/uploads/2014/06/Facebook.mp4
```

does anybody have done something like this before? (I'm very newbie in WP)

Comment: Have you read the [attributes section of the Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes)?

Comment: Yes, I have read that section, but it described how to create and populate atts, and I need to get every single value, I think I will need to create my own function to split the atts

Comment: I think you need to read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [Shortcode API page on the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

> The raw $atts array may include any arbitrary attributes that are specified by the user.

That is to say, the `$atts` parameter passed to your shortcode callback function contains all the attributes in an associative array.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for the PHP function [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
function your_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {

    // compare incoming $atts against defaults and extract out 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'width'         => '12',
        'height'        => '4',
        'file'      => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    if( ! $file )
        return '';

    // do something with the $width, $height, and $file variables

}
```

Comment: [extract is bad, don't use it.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400)

Comment: That's the first I've heard of that. Thanks for the link. Still seems more like it is annoying and not truly "bad".

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to get the $atts of an existing shortcode, I'm not trying to build a shortcode, what I have read about shortcode_atts is that extract(shortcode_atts....) works to merge the array of the existing $atts with a new array of $atts. The idea is that I have to post a comment, and that comment may have a video, the video comes in a shortcode, the problem is that I have to use a flash video player instead of the html5 player, and I have to pass the video url, width and height to work with this video player, so what I need is to split the shortcode.

Comment: You should edit your question then because that wasn't clear. It sounds like you need to unregister the existing shortcode and then add your own... unless the shortcode has a filter you can use to modify the output.